# How to find derivative of sum

Tags: derivatives, summation

How do I find derivative of $f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot \alpha e^{-\alpha (x - k)}$, where $\alpha, \lambda > 0$ is const, $x\geq 0$?

At first I thought to find derivative for every element of sum but it feels kind of wrong since k depends from x (for example last element $\frac{\lambda^{\lfloor x \rfloor} e^{-\lambda}}{(\lfloor x \rfloor)!}\cdot \alpha e^{-\alpha (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)}$).

Comment: Actually we can derivate by components, can't we? I remember that there is a trick to calculate $x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \dots$ by finding derivative of $x + x^2 + \dots$. Then we can do the same thing for this sum. Is it correct?

Comment: Between any two consecutive integers $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is constant, so you can differentiate term by term this finite sum. The function is discontinuous when $x$ is integer and so does not have a derivative at those integer points.